# F# - Sanity Checks and Options

Tags: f#

I'm pretty new to F# so it's hard for me to change my mindset after many years of C#/Java OOP.

I have an event handler `MyForm.SelectFile(filePath:String)` that opens a dialog and let you select the file to read. Once the file is selected, `Parser.LoadFile(filePath:String)` is called:

```
static member LoadFile(filePath:String) =
    if not <| ZipFile.IsZipFile(filePath) then
        failwith "invalid file specified."
    use zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath)
    if zipFile.Count <> 2 || zipFile |> Seq.exists(fun x -> x.FileName <> "alpha" && x.FileName <> "beta")  then
        failwith "invalid file specified."
    zipFile |> fun x -> Parser.Parse(x.OpenReader())
```

I'm always expecting the selected file to be a valid zip archive containing 2 files without extension: "alpha" and "beta".

First, is there a better way to sanitize my input?

My if statements are pretty long and I'm sure F# can provide better solutions, but I really can't figure out.

Second, using `failwith` is forcing me to handle exceptions in my `MyForm.SelectFile(filePath:String)` method and I think Options could be a better solution.

I can't figure out how to use them if I need to perform two different and consecutive checks (`ZipFile.IsZipFile` and content) because in between I have to instantiate a `ZipFile`.

In C# I would just return `null` whenever a check fails and then checking the return value against `null` would let me know whether I need to prompt an error or continue.

Current code:

```
type Parser with

    static member isValidZipFile (zipFile:ZipFile) =
        (zipFile.Count = 2) && (zipFile |> Seq.forall(fun x -> (x.FileName = "alpha") || (x.FileName = "beta")))

    static member LoadFile(filePath:String) =
        if not <| ZipFile.IsZipFile(filePath) then
            None
        else
            use zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath)
            if not <| Parser.isValidZipFile(zipFile) then
                None
            else
                Some(seq { for zipEntry in zipFile do yield Parser.Parse(zipEntry.OpenReader()) } |> Seq.toArray)
```

Comment: Consider submitting a more complete portion of code (that compiles) in Code Review. You'll get more detailed answers on how to functionally structure your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the last line of your function could be a bit more elegant if it was written like:

```
zipFile.OpenReader() |> Parser.Parse
```

Second, you're on the right track as far as your thinking about using `Option`. It's really pretty simple in this case:

```
static member LoadFile(filePath:String) =
    if not <| ZipFile.IsZipFile(filePath) then None else
    use zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath)
    if zipFile.Count <> 2 || zipFile |> Seq.exists(fun x -> x.FileName <> "alpha" && x.FileName <> "beta") then None else
    Some (zipFile.OpenReader() |> Parser.Parse)
```

That last line could also be written as:

```
zipFile.OpenReader() |> Parser.Parse |> Some
```

Now, you mentioned that you don't like the long `if` statement. Let's turn it into a function! And I usually prefer functions with "positive" names, i.e. an `isValidInput` function is usually more helpful than an `isInvalidInput`. So let's make a function that checks if a zipfile is actually valid:

```
let isValid (z:ZipFile) =
    z.Count = 2 && z |> Seq.forAll(fun x -> x.FileName = "alpha" || x.FileName = "beta")
```

Now your `LoadFile` function can become:

```
static member LoadFile(filePath:String) =
    if not <| ZipFile.IsZipFile(filePath) then None else
    use zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath)
    if not <| isValid zipFile then None else
    zipFile.OpenReader() |> Parser.Parse |> Some
```

And that looks pretty easy to read, so we can stop refactoring for now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Everything works like a charm, except the fact that I need to parse every file inside the zip and return every parsing result. I updated my answer showing the actual code... I'm wondering whether what I did is correct and also if is Array is the best choice for me to store the parsing results (they need to be written back to the zip file after some processing that involves changing a few parsed values).

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code looks *weird*. Using Sequence expressions for such a simple piece of code is overkill.

```
Some(seq { for zipEntry in zipFile do yield Parser.Parse(zipEntry.OpenReader()) } |> Seq.toArray)
```

You could write it better like this

```
zipFile |> Seq.map (fun ze -> ze.OpenReader () |> Parser.parse) |> Some
```

Or if you insist in doing it in an array (why?)

```
zipFile |> Seq.map (fun ze -> ze.OpenReader () |> Parser.parse) |> Seq.toArray |> Some
```

You'll end up with type signature `option<seq<value>>`.  I am not sure if this is a good idea, but it is not possible to tell without looking at the rest of your code.